# Extract SEO urls using pre_mattch_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have pages which contains links to other pages. How will I extract all the href which starts with specific name

like my page as tag

```
<a href="shows/film/lop-film/">Some Text</a>
<a href="movie/current/lop-film/">Some Text</a>
<a href="rot.company.com/sow/test/page/asd.mov"></a>


$search = '/<a\s+(?:[^"\'>]+|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*href=("[^"]+"|\'[^\']+\'|[^<>\s]+)/i'
preg_match_all($search, $Content, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $value) {
     print_r('Links :'.$value);
}
```

It extracts but returns unwanted urls linked to external websites and emails

```
 http://www.amazon.co.uk/
 mailto:sp@company.com
```

I mainly want to filter the match which starts with show | movie | domain.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex pattern to

```
$search = '/<a\s+(?:[^"\'>]+|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*href=("(show|movie|domain\.name)[^"]+"|\'(show|movie|domain\.name)[^\']+\'|(show|movie|domain\.name)[^<>\s]+)/i';
```

Duplication of `(show|movie|domain\.name)` looks ugly, but since you have to deal with href attribute with single or double quote I didn't find a nicer way. In general neither `"` or `'` should be part of an url but who knows..

But working on HTML Dom usually its better to use [PHP DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) instead of regex.